# C# byte array conversion to VB.NET

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, byte

As per my last question I'm borrowing some code from the Opus project to integrate into VB.NET software.

Consider

```
byte[] buff = _encoder.Encode(segment, segment.Length, out len);
```

which I've translated to:

```
Dim buff(wavEnc.Encode(segment, segment.Length, len)) As Byte
```

It is throwing a:

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to 'Integer' error...

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim buff = wavEnc.Encode(segment, segment.Length, len)
```

Of course you can do a direct translation of the c#:

```
Dim buff As Byte() = wavEnc.Encode(segment, segment.Length, len)
```

No need for a type at all - let the compiler figure it out.

Comment: This answer has the correct translation, but I'll add that "Let the compiler figure it out" is fine, as long as you really mean the compiler (Option Infer), and not the runtime (Option Strict Off).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Good point. I **always** have `Option Infer On` and `Option Strict On` when working in VB.NET. I would hope everyone would, but you're probably right that not everyone does.

Answer (score 0):

`_encoder.Encode()` is the right-hand side of an assignment.  The left-hand side is a byte array.

The way you are using it in your VB sample is as an array dimensioner: an Integer.